# Why does GetThumbnailImage create blurry images

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating thumbnails of images. I've implemented the thumbnail display in two ways

1 - given an image, create a new thumbnail using the above method.

2 - given an image, grab the dimensions, calculate the resized dimensions and then set that as the dimensions of the PictureBox. The PictureBox is set to auto-zoom mode, so it will scale the image down to 1/4.

Both methods generate thumbs that are 1/4 the original size of the input image (display only, I am not worried about saving or working with the image), but the second method produces a much clearer thumbnail, although I guess it would use more memory since I don't think zooming the control actually affects the image.

Why is the resulting thumbnail very blurry when `GetThumbnailImage` is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the remarks in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx):

> If the [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) contains an embedded thumbnail image, this method retrieves the embedded thumbnail and scales it to the requested size. If the [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) does not contain an embedded thumbnail image, this method creates a thumbnail image by scaling the main image.
>
> The **GetThumbnailImage** method works well when the requested thumbnail image has a size of about 120 x 120 pixels. If you request a large thumbnail image (for example, 300 x 300) from an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) that has an embedded thumbnail, there could be a noticeable loss of quality in the thumbnail image. It might be better to scale the main image (instead of scaling the embedded thumbnail) by calling the [DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx) method.

So it can happen that you get an up-scaled embedded thumbnail.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I looked around and noticed that some devs are flipping their images twice to get rid of this extra information. Though, that would require extra processing to actually flip the images which may be undesirable.